# Excel VBA Progress Bar with userform

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to learn how to use a progress bar with a userform.

The problem I have, with my code, is that it displays the progress bar after  running the loop; it should be running the loop while showing the progress bar instead like 10%...20%...30%...40%......100%.

Can anyone help me fix my code to achieve this?

```
'-----Below is loop-----------------------------------------------------
Sub looprange()
   Dim r As Range
'----------loop thru 0 to 9 ---------------
   For Each r In Sheet6.Range("j2", Range("j" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))

      Sheet6.Range("i2").Value = r.Value

      ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 11
      Application.CutCopyMode = False

      Call print_jpeg

   Next r

   MsgBox "done"

End Sub
```

--

```
'--------Below is vba code in userform :------------
Private Sub UserForm_Activate()

    Dim remainder As Long
    Dim i As Long, j As Long

    Call looprange

    remainder = 0

    For i = 1 To 200

        UserForm1.Label2.Width = UserForm1.Label2.Width + 1

        If i Mod 2 = 0 Then
            remainder = remainder + 1
            UserForm1.Caption = remainder & ” % complete”
            UserForm1.Label2.Caption = remainder & “%”
        End If

        For j = 1 To 600

            DoEvents

        Next j

    Next i

    MsgBox “Loading of program complete.”

    Unload UserForm1

End Sub
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe a true status bar is not included in standard VBA (without references), however you can abuse a label control. Be aware that this method trades performance for user clarity (the user can see that the application is working, but it is slower than the same application without the status bar)

Simply add three labels, one for status text, one for the actual moving bar and one for full bar border. And format them to fit your application (see image below):[image: image visualizing the VBA progress bar setup]

Code below:

```
Private Sub cbStart_Click()
 one_percent_bar_width = lLoadBar.Width / 100 'width of one percent of the total loading bar
 max_numbers = 1000 'only for demo purpose

 Me.lLoadingBar.Visible = True
 For i = 0 To max_numbers 'your loop here

     'your code here

   percentage = i / max_numbers * 100 'calculation of progress, replace i and max_numbers to fit your loop
   Me.lStatus.Caption = percentage & "% complete" 'status percentage text
   Me.lLoadingBar.Width = percentage * one_percent_bar_width 'width of actual blue bar
   DoEvents 'slows down code but only way to make the bar visibly move, tradeoff between user clarity and speed
 Next i 'edit to fit your loop
 Me.lStatus.Caption = "Complete!" 'adjust status to whatever you want
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
 Me.lLoadingBar.Visible = False 'hide the small blue bar
 Me.lStatus.Caption = "Progress not started" 'adjust status to whatever you want
End Sub
```

Comment: I got the code working now, thank you so much for your sharing!

Answer (score 1):

There are a few issues with your code, but to focus on the Progress Bar part, I'll share an example of one way to handle a progress bar in Excel (using the built-in status bar).

Instead of actually doing anything useful, this example is pausing for a split second between loops, but reports the status on the status bar.)  Hopefully it will give you some ideas.

```
Sub ProgressBarTest()

    Const LoopsToRun = 500
    Dim z As Integer

    For z = 1 To LoopsToRun
        'put a random number in A1
        Range("A1") = Int(Rnd() * 100) + 1

        'update status bar
        Application.StatusBar = "Progress: " & Format((z / LoopsToRun), "0.0%")

        'pause for .3 seconds (instead of pausing, you'd run your actual procedure here)
        Pause (0.1)
    Next z

    Application.StatusBar = "Complete!"

End Sub

Sub Pause(sec As Single)
    'pauses for [sec] second
    Dim startTime As Single
    startTime = Timer
    Do While Timer < startTime + sec
        DoEvents
    Loop
End Sub
```

More info [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/application-statusbar-property-excel) and [here](http://datapigtechnologies.com/blog/index.php/show-a-progress-meter-in-the-status-bar/).

Comment: Thank you for your help, can I achieve this using user form? Not status bar at the bottom of excel.

Answer (score 0):

VBA has a **progress bar control** that can be added to forms. While you are learning, you can simply add this control to the form and then update that control during the loop where you are doing the useful form functions. The progress bar controls includes useful properties such as min and max.

If you are doing multiple things in your form, you can update a label to tell the user what is progressing as well as the amount of progress.

[More advanced] In some of my previous work, I have set up VBA routines to run in the background and created a progress bar form using events. This allows for a more sophisticated view with progress statements as well as a percentage run. But the basis of this form is still the progress bar control. While using events is more complicated it allowed me to make a more general  progress bar form that can be used by any of my vba functions and these functions are then unaffected by any changes I make to the form because the events act as a kind of standard interface.

**Update from a comment** by @MathieuGuindon: "The control is actually a VB6 control and will only work in a 32-bit VBA host with the .OCX properly registered, which is getting more and more challenging to do with the more recent Windows versions; referencing and using these controls in VBA7 is heavily discouraged."

Comment: The control is actually a VB6 control and will only work in a 32-bit VBA host with the .OCX properly registered, which is getting more and more challenging to do with the more recent Windows versions; referencing and using these controls in VBA7 is heavily discouraged.